# how to index a one way relation table?

Tags: sql, indexing, outer-join

I'm not a DB guy so this may be a trivial question...

Suppose
1) i have a relation table (I think that's what it's called), student_class, which holds a student_id and a class_id, (representing a many-to-many between a student table and a class table)
2) i do various query that results in a student_id (perhaps among other things) and then the results are "LEFT OUTER JOIN"ed to the student_class and LOJed again to the class table to get the associated class information.
3) i do that a lot, but i don't care to find the students from a given class, or any other thing you may think is common to do in the context of students and classes.
4) i have tens of thousands of students but only about 100 classes
5a) 99% of the students are not enrolled in any class (what a great school) and the rest are enrolled in only and only 1 class
5b) alternatively to 5a, on the average, every student is enrolled in about 2 classes

So how many and which of the indices below should i create in the student_class table for this sole purpose, and is the answer different for 5a and 5b?
a. index on student_id
b. index both student_id and class_id
c. index on class_id

Answer (score 1):

I would create one index for each column.

There's not an argument from your question to only add index to class_id. You select values according to student_id and to class_id, so i think it's reasonable to have them both.

Additionally, your index needs don't change if there are more students enrolled in each class. 
You make use of the indexes in the same way for both cases.

And for the amount of records you have, the indexes are going to be relatively small.